# How to use Linq2Xml to remove nodes with identical value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've got a xml file which is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<front>
    <mtext>a+l</mtext>
    <keyword-group type="Fis">
        <kwd>Tove</kwd>
        <kwd>Jani</kwd>
        <kwd>Reminder</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <keyword-group type="Lio">
        <kwd>Saio</kwd>
        <kwd>Tove</kwd>
        <kwd>EMP</kwd>
        <kwd>CSTC</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <keyword-group type="LioFree">
        <kwd>Iola</kwd>
        <kwd>Jani</kwd>
        <kwd>Priest</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <title>Iatola of rocknrolla</title>
</front>
```

I want to remove all `<kwd>` nodes having the same value while keeping the first one. So the output xml file should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<front>
    <mtext>a+l</mtext>
    <keyword-group type="Fis">
        <kwd>Tove</kwd>
        <kwd>Jani</kwd>
        <kwd>Reminder</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <keyword-group type="Lio">
        <kwd>Saio</kwd>
        <kwd>EMP</kwd>
        <kwd>CSTC</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <keyword-group type="LioFree">
        <kwd>Iola</kwd>
        <kwd>Priest</kwd>
    </keyword-group>
    <title>Iatola of rocknrolla</title>
</front>
```

I did

```
XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Load(@"C:\docm\12345.xml");

            xdoc.Descendants("kwd")
                .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Value)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Take(1))
                .Remove();
```

But the xml file remains unchanged...what did I miss?

Comment: I think you want `Skip(1)` so you'll have the ones you want to remove.  Also you have to save `xdoc` back to the file `xdoc.Save(@"C:\docm\12345.xml");`.

Comment: @juharr where do I add `Skip(1)`?

Comment: Replace the `Take(1)` with `Skip(1)`, otherwise you're removing the first instance of the duplicates instead of keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Load(@"D:\test\12345.XML",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

xdoc.Descendants("kwd")
 .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Value.ToLower())
 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
 .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
 .Remove();

xdoc.Save(@"D:\test\12345.XML",SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

This will work even when the values of the node `kwd` have different cases.
If you don't want to preserve whitespaces ignore `LoadOptions` and `SaveOptions` part.